# Sensitivity of 3D/pressure/force-touch sensor in iPhone 6S in real, physical terms

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

There are 10 trillion reviews/news-stories about the force/3D touch sensors in the iPhone 6S. But has anyone tested how accurate/responsive it is in terms of exact pressure/force measurements? I have trouble finding such info in the torrent of sources covering this at a churnalism level.

I see there's an app that can weight stuff https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Plum-O-Meter so maybe the answer is in its source code... and/or in [the associated blog](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/the-plum-o-meter-weighing-plums-using.html):

> The value displayed is actually the normalised force as a percentage. It's interesting to see that it changes depending on other forces acting upon the screen which to me indicates that the 6s isn't going to replace your high precision electronic scales. What this demo does show is that the 6s can handle multiple touch points each with a decent value for their relative forces.
>
> I did originally build this app for grapes, but they're too light to activate the 3D Touch.

Still it's at a somewhat fluffy level of info.

Comment: Maybe you'll find some useful information here: http://www.techinsights.com/about-techinsights/overview/blog/beyond-apples-force3d-touch-%E2%80%93-is-synaptics-the-key/